# How to beautify javascript code and highlight correspondence of the original code at char number?

Tags: javascript, minify, code-formatting, source-maps, devtools

Is there anyone show me an (online) tool to beautify javascript code and highlight (or show line numbers of) lines of code of the beautified code which are correspondence of the the minified code at specific character number.

For example. I have `setTimeout(() => {console.log(foo.bar)})` and character number 1:32.
I expect a tool which can prettify this code into

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(foo.bar)
})
```

And point out that `2:16` is correspondence of `1:32`

=========

To down-voters: simply, I want to debug production code without sourcemap

Comment: So all you want to do is take the minified code and 'unminify' it?

Comment: yes, but partially. I also want the correspondence of the minified code